# extract RGB channels from a jpeg image in R

Tags: r, jpeg, rgb, raster

In order to classify a jpeg image in R, I would like to get the RGB values of each pixel.

My question: Is there a way to extract RGB channels from a jpeg image in R ?

Comment: Jpeg format does not have layers or channels. Furthermore it is typically in a compressed mode. You will need to convert to a raster format and then extract color pixel by pixel. Probably easier in a program designed for this task or a graphics converted application.

Comment: since the `biOps` package is no longer available, I think the solution using `jpeg` should be made the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have several package to read in JPEG. Here I use package `jpeg`:

```
library(jpeg)
img <- readJPEG("Rlogo.jpg")

dim(img)
[1]  76 100   3
```

As you can see, there is 3 layers: they correspond to your R, G and B values. In each layer, each cell is a pixel.

```
img[35:39,50:54,]
, , 1

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.5098039 0.5921569 0.4549020 0.3372549 0.1921569
[2,] 0.5098039 0.6000000 0.4549020 0.3372549 0.1921569
[3,] 0.5137255 0.6000000 0.4549020 0.3450980 0.1921569
[4,] 0.5215686 0.6039216 0.4627451 0.3450980 0.1921569
[5,] 0.5215686 0.6039216 0.4627451 0.3450980 0.1882353

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.5882353 0.6666667 0.5098039 0.3803922 0.2156863
[2,] 0.5882353 0.6627451 0.5098039 0.3803922 0.2156863
[3,] 0.5843137 0.6627451 0.5098039 0.3764706 0.2156863
[4,] 0.5843137 0.6627451 0.5058824 0.3764706 0.2117647
[5,] 0.5843137 0.6627451 0.5058824 0.3764706 0.2156863

, , 3

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.7254902 0.7921569 0.6156863 0.4588235 0.2705882
[2,] 0.7254902 0.7921569 0.6156863 0.4588235 0.2784314
[3,] 0.7254902 0.7921569 0.6156863 0.4588235 0.2784314
[4,] 0.7176471 0.7921569 0.6156863 0.4666667 0.2862745
[5,] 0.7176471 0.7921569 0.6156863 0.4666667 0.2862745
```

Comment: And you can multiply it by 255 to get the RGB values (a `round(...)` might be required to get rid of those pesky machine rounding errors).

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the `biOps`package for image manipulation.

#### Here is an example:

```
library(biOps)
x <- readJpeg(system.file("samples", "violet.jpg", package="biOps"))
plot(x)

r <- imgRedBand(x)
plot(r)
image(x[,,1])

g <- imgGreenBand(x)
plot(g)
image(x[,,2])

b <- imgBlueBand(x)
plot(b)
image(x[,,3])
```

#### Visual example:

```
redPal <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))
greenPal <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "green"))
bluePal <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "blue"))

x11(width=9, height=2.5)
par(mfcol=c(1,3))
image(x=seq(ncol(r)), y=seq(nrow(r)), z=t(r), asp=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="red channel", col=redPal(256))
image(x=seq(ncol(g)), y=seq(nrow(g)), z=t(g), asp=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="green channel", col=greenPal(256))
image(x=seq(ncol(b)), y=seq(nrow(b)), z=t(b), asp=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="blue channel", col=bluePal(256))
```

[image]

Comment: Just leaving a note for future readers. `biOps` is no longer available in CRAN.

Answer (score 5):

I like the approach via R's `biOps` package. After loading your data into canvas, you're able to convert your jpg file from `imagedata` to `raster` and do some further processing. Here's my code:

```
# Required packages
library(biOps)
library(raster)

# Load and plot data
data(logo)
jpg <- logo

plot.imagedata(jpg)

# Convert imagedata to raster
rst.blue <- raster(jpg[,,1])
rst.green <- raster(jpg[,,2])
rst.red <- raster(jpg[,,3])

# Plot single raster images and RGB composite
plot(stack(rst.blue, rst.green, rst.red), 
     main = c("Blue band", "Green band", "Red band"))
plotRGB(stack(rst.blue, rst.green, rst.red))
```

Comment: By the way, thanks to @Marcinthebox for the nice suggestion via `image(x[,,1])`!

Comment: Ok, perfect answer, much easier to deal with raster. Thank you.

Comment: Just leaving a note for future readers. `biOps` is no longer available in CRAN.