# R - Getting Color Values

Tags: r, jpeg, pixel

I have a jpeg image that I am attempting to extract the RGB values from in R.

Here is the image:

[image]

I am able to access the pixel values quite easily with the following code:

```
library(jpeg)

y <- readJPEG("MOLD_1.jpg")
head(y)
```

This returns:

```
[1] 0.9450980 0.9450980 0.9450980 0.9490196 0.9490196 0.9529412
```

I'm interested in knowing the color values associated with those pixels.  I've tried to use alot of packages to figure this out including raster, pixmap, etc.

I'm struggling pretty bad - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related/Duplicate posts: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163611) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769628)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readJPEG` returns a 3-D array that is `height x width x channels`. You can access individual color values using standard indexing. For example, `y[,,1]` will give you a `height x width` matrix of red intensities. You can convert these to color values using the `rgb()` function:

```
val <- rgb( y[,,1], y[,,2], y[,,3] )
myImg <- matrix( val, dim(y)[1], dim(y)[2] )
```